# Ribbon cable pin order

Tags: pcb-design, connector, cables

I'm struggling to understand the pin order on a ribbon cable.

I want to connect two boards (one main board with the MCU, the other one for the front panel to pots and buttons) and i need a 2x20 connector to connect the boards. I found on Mouser [this connector](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/?qs=84A%2FDAdkstKRjqrk64ONjg%3D%3D) but i can't find the related cable. I don't need to use that specific connector, it is just one that i found searching on Mouser.

On top of that, i need to understand what's the pin order using this cable. Basically how can I connect the two boards without swapping pins.

Answer (score 3):

This diagram shows how the pins on a standard  2x10 ribbon cable connector are numbered and how the ribbon cable conductors are connected to the pins of the connector.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So your connector [5103308-8](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en?keywords=5103308-8) would mate to a connector such as [1658621-9](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1658621-9/AKC40H-ND/825407)

[image]

This is a 40 position connector with a .100" pitch. because it is 2 row you would need a .050" pitch cable. [Here](https://www.digikey.ca/short/ppz4dm) are some options Digi-Key carries. Any disti will have some options depending on the length you need.
-Robert